# how should I re-draw table component with entered value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to call an API with given value for drawing data table.

Here is what I want to do and How the actual code works.

How should I fix it? please I need your kind advice.

- what I want to do

1. draw a table with initial value(with 5 rows).
2. type 2 and click submit button for re-drawing table(with 2 rows)
3. the table should be given with 2 rows.

- How the actual code works

1. draw a table with initial value(with 5 rows).
2. type 2 and click submit button for re-drawing table(with 2 rows).
3. the table is given with 5 rows.

my main code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Table from 'components/advTable';
import { apiProvider } from 'services/modules/provider';


import {
  CBadge,
  CDataTable,
  CCard,
  CCardBody,
  CCardHeader,
  CCol,
  CFormGroup,
  CInput,
  CLabel,
  CSelect,
  CRow,
  CCardFooter,
  CButton,
} from '@coreui/react'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'


const PendingVertification = () => {
 
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(5);
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [countPerPage, setCountPerPage] = useState(5);
  const subURL = "users";

  const onChange = (e : any) => {
    console.log('the Value: ', e.target.value);
    
    //if I enter number 2 and setQuery(2)
    setQuery(e.target.value.toLowerCase());

    
  };

  const onSubmit = (e : any)  => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Call API to draw a table 
    getTableList();
    //setQuery(5);
  };

  

  const getTableList = () => {
    //Call API for table Data with Given values.
    apiProvider.getTabledata(page, query, subURL ).then(res => {   
      setInfo(res.data);
      }).catch(err => {
        setInfo({});
      });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      //Call Rest API only once
     getTableList();
    }, []);

  return (
    <>

    <CRow>
      <CCol xs="12" lg="15">
        <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Sample
              <small> Form</small>
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>

              <CRow>
                <CCol xs="12">
                  <CFormGroup>
                    <CLabel htmlFor="ccnumber">Search Value</CLabel>
                    <CInput id="ccnumber" placeholder="fill this form" onChange={onChange} required />
                  </CFormGroup>
                </CCol>
              </CRow>
            </CCardBody>
            <CCardFooter>
              <CButton type="submit" size="sm" color="primary" onClick={onSubmit}><CIcon name="cil-scrubber"/> Submit</CButton>
              <CButton type="reset" size="sm" color="danger"><CIcon name="cil-ban" /> Reset</CButton>
            </CCardFooter>
        </CCard>
        </CCol>
    </CRow>

      {info && <Table tableData={info} query={query}  subURL = {subURL}/>}      
    </>
    //the code above Draws table with given values 
  );
};
export default PendingVertification;
```

Table component code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import { apiProvider } from 'services/modules/provider';

interface Props {
    tableData: any,
    query: number,
    subURL: string
  }
  
  const Table: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ tableData, query, subURL}) => {
    const columns = [

        {
          name: tableData.mata? tableData.meta.firstColum : 'Avatar',
          cell: (row : any) => <img height="30px" width="30px" alt={row.first_name} src={row.avatar} />
        },
        {
          name: tableData.mata? tableData.meta.secondColum : 'First Name',
          selector: 'first_name'
        },
        {
          name: tableData.mata? tableData.meta.thirdColum : 'Last Name',
          selector: 'last_name'
        },
        {
          name: tableData.mata? tableData.meta.fourthColum : 'e-mail',
          selector: 'email'
        }
      ];
    
      //set The value for drawing table
      // countPerpage should be 2 when I enter 2 but it always contain number 5.
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [countPerPage, setCountPerPage] = useState(query);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<any>({tableData});
    const isMounted = useRef(false);

    const getTableList = async () => {
      //re-draw table with give values.
        const response = await apiProvider.getTabledata(page, countPerPage, subURL);
        setUsers(response);
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        if(isMounted.current) {
        getTableList();
        } else {
          isMounted.current = true;
        }
      }, [page, countPerPage, tableData]);
    
    return (
        <>
        <DataTable
          title="Table (Server side Pagination)"
          columns={columns}
          data={users.data}
          highlightOnHover
          pagination
          paginationServer
          paginationTotalRows={users.total}
          paginationPerPage={countPerPage}
          paginationRowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15, 25, 50]}
          paginationComponentOptions={{
            noRowsPerPage: false
          }}
          onChangeRowsPerPage= { rowsPerPage => setCountPerPage(rowsPerPage)}
          onChangePage={page => setPage(page)}
        />
      </>
    );
  };
  
  
  export default Table;
```

Comment: seems like you want to pass the countPerPage from the parent component to the child, instead of having it inside the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Table component:

```
//New useEffect, keep your other one    
useEffect(() => {setCountPerPage(query)}, [query])
```

Comment: Thank you your code allowed me to one step go forward.